# Is it possible to load ansi encoded string using nodejs

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, ansi, hebrew

I have large quantity of html files (around 2k).
These html`s are result of conversion from word documents.
The files have some hebrew text inside html tags. I can see the text perfectly using vscode or notepad++ editors.

My goal is to loop through the folder and insert the contents of files into some DB. 
Since i have a little knowledge of nodejs - i decided to build the "looping" using node. 
Here is where i finished so far:

```
fs.readdir('./myFolder', function (err, files) {
    total = files.length;

    let fileArr = []
    for(var x=0, l = files.length; x<l; x++) {
      const content = fs.readFileSync(`./myFolder/${files[x]}`, 'utf8');    

      let title = content.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/g).pop()

      fileArr.push({id:files[x] , title})
    }
});
```

The problem is: although the text displayed correctly inside editors -when debugging - i can see that "title" variable get strings which consists of question marks
 [image]

I guess the problem is with file encoding, am i right here?
If so - is there way to decode the string?

P.S. my OS is windows10

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities here, it may be possible that your input files are in a multibyte encoding (such as utf8 utf16 etc) and your debugger is simply not showing the correct characters due to font restrictions.

I would try writing the title variable to some test file like so:

```
fs.writeFileSync(`title-test-${x}.txt`, title, "utf8");
```

And see if the title looks correct in your text editor.

It may also be possible that the files are encoded in an [extended ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) encoding such as Windows 1255 or ISO 8859-8. If this is the case, fs.readFileSync will not work correctly since it does not support these encodings (see [node.js encoding list](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings))

If the files are encoded using a single-byte extended ascii encoding, it should be possible to convert to a more portable encoding (such as utf8).

I'd recommend the [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) module for this purpose, you can do a lot with it!

For example, to convert from a Windows 1255 file to utf8 you could try:

```
    const iconv = require("iconv-lite");
    const fs = require("fs");

    // Convert from an encoded buffer to JavaScript string.
    const fileData = iconv.decode(fs.readFileSync("./hebrew-win1255.txt"),  "win1255");

    // Convert from JavaScript string to a buffer.
    const outputBuffer = iconv.encode(fileData, "utf8");

    // Write output file..
    fs.writeFileSync("./hebrew-utf8-output.txt", outputBuffer);
```

Comment: Great, glad to be of assistance!!